# What's wrong with my simple insert?

Tags: coldfusion, insert, cfquery

I'm using coldfusion to insert the contents of a struct (key-value pairs) into a database table. This is my code:

```
<cfloop collection="#results#" item="ID" >
    <cfquery name="insertStuff" datasource="myDataSource">
        INSERT INTO web..Stuff (ID, Name)
        VALUES (#ID#, #results[ID]#)
    </cfquery>
</cfloop>
```

This seems simple enough... but I'm getting the following error:

```
Incorrect syntax near 'VA'.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You really ought to think about parameterising your data too.

```
<cfloop collection="#results#" item="ID" >
    <cfquery name="insertStuff" datasource="myDataSource">
        INSERT INTO web..Stuff (ID, Name)
        VALUES (
            <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#ID#">, 
            <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#results[ID]#">)
    </cfquery>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: To Steve's point, using the cfqueryparam will do a lot for you. It would have quoted the string 'VA' for you while protecting you from a whole bunch of bad stuff. Even in an Intranet app, you want to do this.

Comment: good point... thanks. I'll definitely try this. I'm getting back into cf after a long break from it... so there're a lot of things I've forgotten about :)

Answer (score 2):

I think I may have solved it... forgot the quotes, and they're both varchar fields :-/

```
<cfloop collection="#results#" item="ID" >
    <cfquery name="insertStuff" datasource="myDataSource">
        INSERT INTO web..Stuff (ID, Name)
        VALUES ('#ID#', '#results[ID]#')
    </cfquery>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: I would still do the CFQueryParam as well.

Comment: Totally agreed.  CFQueryParam is definitely a best practice.  I use CFEclipse's Snippets to make inserting them a breeze (they can be a pain to type).